# Is there anyway to avoid loop in matlab array accessing?

Tags: matlab

I have a 2-D array. And I want to access it with rows and colums index stored in another 2-D array.
Example: Now I don't want to use loops but I want to access A(1, 2) and A(3, 4).

```
A = ones(10,10)
B = [1, 2 ; 3, 4]
```

If I do `A(b(:,1), b(:,2))`, this will result in all possible combination of [1,2] and [3,4].
How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Use MATLAB's sub2ind function:

```
A(sub2ind(size(A),B(:,1),B(:,2)))
```